# Why do I get a crash only sometimes when closing input file with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a problem where only sometimes when I call `avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx)` and it results in `malloc check failed` and my application crashes.

I really need to use `ffmpeg` because I need to grab a thumbnail of a video to show in a list and I cannot find an alternative library.

Can anybody see something in my code where I am doing something wrong when using this library which may cause this malloc check failed problem?

```
bool MuteCamera::PullFrame(  )
{



pMJPEGCodec  = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_MJPEG );


bool bRet = false;
int videoStream   = -1;
AVFrame *pFrame=NULL;
AVFrame *pFrameRGB=NULL;
AVPacket packet;
int frameFinished=0;

//AVDictionary *optionsDict = NULL;
AVInputFormat   *pFormat = NULL;
const char      formatName[] = "mp4";

if (!(pFormat = av_find_input_format(formatName))) {
    printf("can't find input format %s\n", formatName);
    return -1;
}

AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
pFormatCtx=avformat_alloc_context();

if(pFormatCtx == NULL)
{
    printf("\n NULL CONTEXT \n ");
    return -1;
}
if(avformat_open_input (&pFormatCtx, capturedUrl.data(), pFormat, NULL) == 0 )
{
    for(int i=0; i<(int)pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            videoStream=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(videoStream >= 0 )
    {
        AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
        AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
        if(pCodec != NULL)
        {
            if( avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) >= 0 )
            {

                pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();

                if(pFrame != NULL)
                {


                    frameFinished = 0;

                    while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
                    {


                        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
                        {

                            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

                            if(frameFinished)
                            {

                                printf("\n FRAMEFINISHED \n ");
                                QString *uu = new QString(capturedUrl.data());//
                                uu->replace(".mp4", "thumbnail.jpg");
                                WriteJPEG(pCodecCtx, pFrame, uu->toLatin1().data(), PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P);

                                if(viewingVideos && viewingFromDifferent)
                                {
                                    QVariantMap map = QVariantMap();
                                    map["title"] = actualFilename;

                                    map["path"] =  actualFilename.replace(".mp4", "thumbnail.jpg");// QString("asset:///white_photo.png");
                                    m_listDataModel << map;

                                }
                                delete uu;
                                av_free_packet(&packet);
                                break;



                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf("\n FRAMENOTFINISHED \n ");
                            }
                        }
                        av_free_packet(&packet);

                    }




                    av_free(pFrameRGB);

                    av_free(pFrame);

                    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
                    //av_free(pCodecCtx);
                    cout << "\n before free formatctx \n";
                    cout.flush();
                    if(pFormatCtx)
                        avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
                    cout << "\n after free formatctx \n";
                    cout.flush();

                }
                else
                    bRet = false;





            }
            else
                bRet = false;
        }
        else
            bRet = false;
    }
    else
        bRet = false;





}


return bRet;
}


bool WriteJPEG (AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx, AVFrame *pFrame, char cFileName[], PixelFormat pix)
    {
int complete = 0;
bool bRet = false;
int out_buf_size;
uint8_t *out_buf;

AVCodecContext *pMJPEGCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pMJPEGCodec);
if( pMJPEGCtx )
{
    pMJPEGCtx->bit_rate = pCodecCtx->bit_rate;
    pMJPEGCtx->width = pCodecCtx->width;
    pMJPEGCtx->height = pCodecCtx->height;
    pMJPEGCtx->pix_fmt = pix;
    pMJPEGCtx->codec_id = CODEC_ID_MJPEG;
    pMJPEGCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    pMJPEGCtx->time_base.num = pCodecCtx->time_base.num;
    pMJPEGCtx->time_base.den = pCodecCtx->time_base.den;
    pMJPEGCtx->time_base= (AVRational){1,29.7};




    if( pMJPEGCodec && (avcodec_open2( pMJPEGCtx, pMJPEGCodec, NULL) >= 0) )
    {

         AVFrame *oframe;
        oframe = avcodec_alloc_frame();

        if(oframe == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n (oframe == NULL");
            fflush(stdout);
        }


        /* calculate the bytes needed for the output image and create buffer for the output image */
        out_buf_size = avpicture_get_size(pMJPEGCtx->pix_fmt,
                pMJPEGCtx->width,
                pMJPEGCtx->height);
        out_buf = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(out_buf_size * sizeof(uint8_t));
        if (out_buf == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate output data buffer!\n");
            //ret = -ENOMEM;

        }

        avpicture_alloc((AVPicture *)oframe, pMJPEGCtx->pix_fmt, pMJPEGCtx->width, pMJPEGCtx->height);

        struct SwsContext *sws;
        sws = sws_getContext(pMJPEGCtx->width, pMJPEGCtx->height, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                pMJPEGCtx->width, pMJPEGCtx->height, pMJPEGCtx->pix_fmt, SWS_BILINEAR,
                NULL, NULL, NULL);

        sws_scale(sws, (const uint8_t **)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize,
                0, pMJPEGCtx->height, &oframe->data[0], &oframe->linesize[0]);
        sws_freeContext(sws);





        AVPacket pp2;
        av_init_packet(&pp2);
        pp2.data = NULL;
        pp2.size = 0;
        avcodec_encode_video2(pMJPEGCtx, &pp2,  oframe, &complete);
        if(complete)
        {
            printf("\n packet recieved");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n packet NOT recieved");
            fflush(stdout);
        }

        if( SaveFrameJpeg(pp2.size, pp2.data, cFileName ) )
            bRet = true;

            av_free(oframe);



            avcodec_close(pMJPEGCtx);

        av_free_packet(&pp2);
        av_free(out_buf);

            av_free(pMJPEGCtx);


    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n problem!!");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return bRet;
}
}

bool SaveFrameJpeg(int nszBuffer, uint8_t *buffer, char cOutFileName[])
{
bool bRet = false;
FILE *pFile;
if( nszBuffer > 0 )
{

    if(0 == 0 )
    {
        printf("\n start SaveFrameJpeg=%d",nszBuffer );
        fflush(stdout);
        pFile= fopen(cOutFileName, "wb");
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), nszBuffer, pFile);
        bRet = true;
        fclose(pFile);
        printf("\n end SaveFrameJpeg=%d",nszBuffer );
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
return bRet;
}


bool newPullFrame(const std::string& capturedUrl)
{

AVCodec* pMJPEGCodec  = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_MJPEG );

int videoStream   = -1;

AVDictionary *optionsDict = NULL;
AVInputFormat   *pFormat = NULL;
const char      formatName[] = "mp4";

if (!(pFormat = av_find_input_format(formatName)))
{
    std::cout << "can't find input format " << formatName << "\n";
    return false;
}

AVFormatContextHandle FormatCtx(avformat_alloc_context());

if(!FormatCtx.is_valid())
{
    std::cout << "\n NULL CONTEXT \n ";
    return false;
}

if(avformat_open_input (&FormatCtx, capturedUrl.c_str(), pFormat, NULL))
    return false;

for(int i=0; i<(int)FormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
{
    if(FormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        videoStream=i;
        break;
    }
}
if(videoStream < 0 )
    return false;

CodecContextHandle CodecCtx(FormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec, avcodec_close);
AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(CodecCtx->codec_id);

if(pCodec == NULL)
    return false;

if( avcodec_open2(CodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict) < 0 )
    return false;

FrameHandle Frame(avcodec_alloc_frame(), av_free);

if(!Frame.is_valid())
    return false;

int frameFinished=0;
AVPacket packet;

while(av_read_frame(FormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
{

    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
    {
        avcodec_decode_video2(CodecCtx, Frame, &frameFinished, &packet);

        if(frameFinished)
        {

            std::string uu (capturedUrl);
            size_t pos = capturedUrl.rfind(".mp4");
            uu.replace(pos, 4, "thumbnail.jpg");
            // save the frame to file
            int Bytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P, CodecCtx->width, CodecCtx->height);
            BufferHandle buffer((uint8_t*)av_malloc(Bytes*sizeof(uint8_t)), av_free);
            CodecContextHandle OutContext(avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL), free_context);

            OutContext->bit_rate = CodecCtx->bit_rate;

            OutContext->width = CodecCtx->width;
            OutContext->height = CodecCtx->height;
            OutContext->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P;
            OutContext->codec_id = CODEC_ID_MJPEG;
            OutContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
            OutContext->time_base.num = CodecCtx->time_base.num;
            OutContext->time_base.den = CodecCtx->time_base.den;
            OutContext->time_base= (AVRational){1,29.7};
            AVCodec *OutCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(OutContext->codec_id);
            avcodec_open2(OutContext, OutCodec, NULL);
            OutContext->mb_lmin = OutContext->lmin = OutContext->qmin * 118;
            OutContext->mb_lmax = OutContext->lmax = OutContext->qmax * 118;
            OutContext->flags = 2;
            OutContext->global_quality = OutContext->qmin * 118;
            Frame->pts = 1;

            Frame->quality = OutContext->global_quality;

            int ActualSize = avcodec_encode_video(OutContext, buffer, Bytes, Frame);

            std::ofstream file(uu.data(), std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out);
            file.write((const char*)(uint8_t*)buffer, ActualSize);
            file.close();
            av_free_packet(&packet);
            av_free(Frame);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << " new pullframe frameNOTfinished\n";
                            cout.flush();
        }
        //if(CodecCtx->refcounted_frames == 1)

            av_free(Frame);

    }
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: I cleaned the code up a bit before posting which removed a break out of the while loop and now due to an edit by Rohan I can't insert my break so please bear in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to move your call to `av_free_packet(&packet)` inside your while loop. So you currently have:

```
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
{
     // A bunch of operations here
}
// this is not the right place for this
av_free_packet(&packet);
```

Instead you should have

```
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
{
     // A bunch of operations here

    // this needs to be called for every call to av_read_frame()
    // so it must be inside the while loop
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

See [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61) for further details.

Considering that you writing this in C++ you could consider creating some simple [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) wrappers around these resources to make your resource management much easier.

**EDIT**

Based on your feedback it seems that this change that I recommended didn't do it. So I revisited the code. I implemented my own save to Jpeg as I could not see yours - though for test purposes it simply keeps over-writing the same file.

In order to simplify the code and get a handle on the resource management I implemented some "smart pointers" for the ffmpeg resources. These automatically clean up at scope exit. I cannot see a resource leak when running through this code and it correctly generates each frame as a jpeg file.

See if you get any value out of this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavdevice\avdevice.h>
#include <libavformat\avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter\avfilter.h>
#include <libavcodec\avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale\swscale.h>
}
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename D>
class AVHandle
{
    T *val;
    typedef D* deleter_t;
    deleter_t deleter;

    // not default constructible
    AVHandle();
    // non copiable
    AVHandle(const AVHandle&);
    AVHandle& operator=(const AVHandle&);
public:
    AVHandle(T *in, deleter_t del) : val(in), deleter(del)
    {}

    operator T *()
    {
        return val;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return val;
    }

    bool is_valid()
    {
        return val != 0;
    }

    ~AVHandle()
    {
        deleter(val);
    }
};
typedef AVHandle<AVFrame, void (void*)> FrameHandle;
typedef AVHandle<AVCodecContext, int (AVCodecContext*)> CodecContextHandle;
typedef AVHandle<uint8_t, void(void*)> BufferHandle;

class AVFormatContextHandle
{
    AVFormatContext *val;

    // not default constrcutible
    AVFormatContextHandle();
    // non copiable
    AVFormatContextHandle(const AVFormatContextHandle&);
    AVFormatContextHandle& operator=(const AVFormatContextHandle&);
public:
    AVFormatContextHandle(AVFormatContext *ctx) : val(ctx)
    {}

    operator AVFormatContext *()
    {
        return val;
    }

    AVFormatContext* operator ->()
    {
        return val;
    }

    AVFormatContext** operator&()
    {
        return &val;
    }

    bool is_valid()
    {
        return val != 0;
    }

    ~AVFormatContextHandle()
    {
        if(val)
            avformat_close_input(&val);
    }
};

int free_context(AVCodecContext* c)
{
    int ret = avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    return ret;
}

bool PullFrame(const std::string& capturedUrl)
{
    AVCodec* pMJPEGCodec  = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_MJPEG );

    int videoStream   = -1;

    AVDictionary *optionsDict = NULL;
    AVInputFormat   *pFormat = NULL;
    const char      formatName[] = "mp4";

    if (!(pFormat = av_find_input_format(formatName))) 
    {
        std::cout << "can't find input format " << formatName << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    AVFormatContextHandle FormatCtx(avformat_alloc_context());

    if(!FormatCtx.is_valid())
    {
        std::cout << "\n NULL CONTEXT \n ";
        return false;
    }

    if(avformat_open_input (&FormatCtx, capturedUrl.c_str(), pFormat, NULL))
        return false;

    for(int i=0; i<(int)FormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if(FormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            videoStream=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(videoStream < 0 )
        return false;

    CodecContextHandle CodecCtx(FormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec, avcodec_close);
    AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(CodecCtx->codec_id);

    if(pCodec == NULL)
        return false;

    if( avcodec_open2(CodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict) < 0 )
        return false;

    FrameHandle Frame(avcodec_alloc_frame(), av_free);

    if(!Frame.is_valid())
        return false;

    int frameFinished=0;
    AVPacket packet;

    while(av_read_frame(FormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
    {
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
        {
            avcodec_decode_video2(CodecCtx, Frame, &frameFinished, &packet);

            if(frameFinished)
            {
                std::string uu (capturedUrl);
                size_t pos = capturedUrl.rfind(".mp4");
                uu.replace(pos, 4, "thumbnail.jpg");
                // save the frame to file
                int Bytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P, CodecCtx->width, CodecCtx->height);
                BufferHandle buffer((uint8_t*)av_malloc(Bytes*sizeof(uint8_t)), av_free);
                CodecContextHandle OutContext(avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL), free_context);
                OutContext->bit_rate = CodecCtx->bit_rate;
                OutContext->width = CodecCtx->width;
                OutContext->height = CodecCtx->height;
                OutContext->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P;
                OutContext->codec_id = CODEC_ID_MJPEG;
                OutContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
                OutContext->time_base.num = CodecCtx->time_base.num;
                OutContext->time_base.den = CodecCtx->time_base.den;
                AVCodec *OutCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(OutContext->codec_id);
                avcodec_open2(OutContext, OutCodec, NULL);
                OutContext->mb_lmin = OutContext->lmin = OutContext->qmin * 118;
                OutContext->mb_lmax = OutContext->lmax = OutContext->qmax * 118;
                OutContext->flags = 2;
                OutContext->global_quality = OutContext->qmin * 118;

                Frame->pts = 1;
                Frame->quality = OutContext->global_quality;

                int ActualSize = avcodec_encode_video(OutContext, buffer, Bytes, Frame);
                std::ofstream file("c:\\temp\\output.jpg", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out);
                file.write((const char*)(uint8_t*)buffer, ActualSize);
            }
            if(CodecCtx->refcounted_frames == 1)
                av_frame_unref(Frame);
        }
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    av_register_all();
    while(true)
        PullFrame("c:\\temp\\sample_mpeg4.mp4");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Peter, I have move followed your advice and everything seems ok now (executed the function many many times since changing the position of av_free_packet(&packet) and no fail!) but I have been trying to solve this for a couple of weeks now and thought I have solved it only for it to appear again so i'll give it til the end of the day and come back and close the thread hopefully if it solved. Thank you again.

Comment: unfortunately the malloc check failed crash has occurred again at the same point - what exactly does this error mean please?

Comment: I haven't had the time to look into it more deeply. However I believe it is a symptom of the same issue that I highlighted. The resource management (and here I mean memory allocation) does not look balanced - meaning there is not a free() for all allocations in all code paths. You're either getting a heap corruption or some form of heap starvation.

Comment: I'm looking at my WriteJpeg() function and that also uses ffmpeg and after reading your last comment I'm thinking it could be a problem which may lay somewhere else like WriteJpeg(). Please correct me if I'm wrong. The problem is I cannot edit my question to show that other function.

Comment: I got around to experimenting with the implementation. I edited the original answer and that will hopefully provide some insights for you.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I am really hopeful now (this bug is really getting me down) but I have an unresolved inclusion for type_traits - I have created a cpp class called AVHandle and pasted your code apart from int main. I am using Blackberry 10 sdk and I will keep searching myself but initial search shows not much to help me - do you have any ideas (if i remove this inclusion I get a lot of errors so i think it is needed)?

Comment: looks like I should be using boost on the bb 10 platform and so i have the boost folder pasted in to my src folder and I can include some boost hpp with any unresolved inclusions errors. However I get 'AVHandle' is not a template type error at the start of the class - should i have pasted the code you provided into a file called AVHandle.cpp? Please bear with me if I am doing something stupid - I am still learning about c++ programming.

Comment: Actually you should not need type_traits - it was part of a different experiment. I was trying to create one universal Handle class, but it wasn't worth the effort and would require either boost or a C++11 compiler and I thought that was risky. So pull it and see how you go. I tried to keep it to C++03 compatible code.

Comment: You should also be able to pull swscale.h (I was going to use it to save the JPG file but changed course on that).

Comment: There is no need for a separate AVHandle.cpp file - if anything put it into a .h file and #include it.

Comment: Just reading your initial comment above. If you have a break in your while loop you need to make sure that you clean up your packet just before the break as well as at the end of the while loop - av_free_packet() needs to be called when exiting the loop. I could not easily wrap it in a handle because of the way it is allocated. But please note that the current implementation saves _every_ frame. I believe you only want 1 - so be sure you clean it up.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have added all code inc WriteJpeg() to clarify as you have read my code a few times but it was missing the break and I did change av_free(&packet).

Comment: I pasted AVHandle code into AVHandle.h and removed type_triats but now I get av_frame_unref not found and CodecCtx has no refcounted_frames so maybe I have a different version of ffmpeg (it was prebuilt for me) - I tried to include frame.h and avutil\frame.h but they are not found.

Comment: Just eliminate those lines for now - I'm using the very latest release. You can review that later if a resource leak is found. For now let's just eliminate any possible source error from your existing implementation. The handle wrappers for the ffmpeg resources will help significantly there.

Comment: thanks, it's gets no further (must crash) than Frame->pts = 1; and in the output I see [mjpeg @ 885f280] framerate not set. I tried adding OutContext->time_base= (AVRational){1,29.7}; but this doesn't get rid of the warning or the crash.

Comment: Hmm, must be caused by having different versions of ffmpeg. It's a bit hard with just a quick glance to check the resource management in your WriteJPEG() function. That's the advantage of wrapping it so that destructors do the clean up. Unfortunately ffmpeg does not lend itself to this as cleanly as some APIs.

Comment: strange thing is I coment out Frame->pts = 1; and the still the following lines dont get called which are std::cout << " new pullframe after frame->pts \n";
                cout.flush(); so thats confusing.

Comment: ignore last comment, I have a thumbnail - it needed a clean before build for some reason and adding  OutContext->time_base= (AVRational){1,29.7}; did in fact get rid of the warning. As stated on Saturday this is very intermittent so I will hopefully be closing the thread tonight after extensive testing - your kindness and time is massively appreciated Peter.

Comment: everything is looking good! - I have added my function from AVHandle to the code in the question (newPullFrame) as I had to add file.close() and av_free(Frame) and so wanted to make sure I've not added something which could cause problems _ I did get Malloc check failed before I added these tweaks after capturing a few thumbnails so it seems necessary.